# $Z_n \stackrel{a.s.}{\to} 0$ and $E(|Z_n|) \to 0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Let $Z_n$ be a sequence of random variables with finite expectation. Is the following statement true?
>
> i) $Z_n \stackrel{a.s.}{\to} 0$ implies $E(|Z_n|) \to 0$
>
> ii) $E(|Z_n|) \to 0$ implies $Z_n \stackrel{\mathrm{a.e.}}{\to} 0$

This problems came to my mind when I found that [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Properties_4) do not provide any information on relationship between almost sure convergence and convergence in $1$st order mean.

Edit 1: Okay so I find that if I define $Z_n=0$ with probability $1-\frac{1}{n^2}$ and $Z_n=n^2$ with probability $\frac1{n^2}$. Then $E(Z_n)=1$. Define $A_n=(Z_n\neq 0)$. Clearly
$$\sum P(A_n) <\infty.$$
Hence by first Borel-Cantelli Lemma, we have $P(\limsup A_n)=0$ which implies $Z_n \stackrel{a.s}{\to} 0$. This contradicts (i).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You example in order for i) is correct.

For ii), consider a probability space and a sequence of independent events $(A_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ of probability $1/n$. Then define $Z_n$ as the characteristic function of $A_n$ and use the second Borel-Cantelli's lemma.

Comment: Thank you! Actually I'm an aspiring probabilist. Nice to know you are working on probability too.